# Handling back button in MVVM architecture in Android

Tags: android, mvvm

I have two fragments A & B set up with the Android Navigation Component. Fragment A contains a recyclerView in which an item click will navigate to Fragment B.

The issue is when I click the up / back button inside Fragment B, it will not navigate back to Fragment A but will reload Fragment A and B. I still see Fragment B.

In the Fragment A I've also floatingactionbutton which navigate to Fagment B and it works perfect.

I also use ViewModel + DataBinding for RecyclerView.

Here is how I've implemented navigation :
Layout for item of Recyclerview

```
<layout>
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="position"
        type="java.lang.Integer" />
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="SmsListViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onItemClick(position)}">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<layout>
```

ViewModel:

```
private var clicked = MutableLiveData<Long>()
fun getClicked(): MutableLiveData<Long> {
    return clicked
}

fun onItemClick(index: Int) {
    val threadId = smsList.value!!.get(index).threadId
    clicked.value = threadId
}
```

Fragment A

```
smsListViewModel.getClicked().observe(this, Observer<Long> { clicked ->
        if (clicked != null) {
            val action = SmsListFragmentDirections.actionListSmsToConservation(clicked)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    })
```

And code for button in Fragment A which it works:
When I go to Fragment B and press up / back button I return to Fragment A.

```
floating_action_button.setOnClickListener { view ->
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_conservation)
    }
```

Where is problem? I try without Directions class but not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Viewmodel (smsListViewModel) sitll has clicked != null. It is reloaded with this property and the Observer is called again. Do smth like:

```
smsListViewModel.getClicked().observe(this, Observer<Long> { clicked ->
    if (clicked != null) {
        val action = SmsListFragmentDirections.actionListSmsToConservation(clicked)
        smsListViewModel.setClicked(null)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
})
```

You may need

```
fun setClicked(value: Int?){
  clicked.value = value
}
```